# How to close a log file Python

Tags: python, logging

I want to close my log file because when I relaunch a class in my Software, it writes in the previous log file. Here's a part of the code:

```
class nmeaManager(object) :

    def __init__(self,source_file,gps_solution,log_file,update_rate):


        ### Get the Source File 
        ############################################## 
        self.source = source_file

        ### Get the Gps solution depending on the name of the file
        ##############################################
        self.gps_solution = gps_solution

        ### Get the Destination File
        ##############################################
        self.destination = log_file

        ###Set the Destination file
        ##############################################
        logging.basicConfig(filename=self.destination,filemode='w',format= "[%(asctime)s]%(message)s",level=logging.DEBUG)

        #Get update_rate
        self.update_rate = update_rate

        ###Start the ckecking cycle
        ##############################################
        self.start(self.gps_solution,self.update_rate,self.source)
        self.stop(self.destination)
```

I don't know if there is someting like logging.close() or something?

Comment: Change `filemode='w'` to `filemode='a'` and it will append to the logfile, rather than overwrite it?

Comment: Yes but I don't want to append, I want to have a new log file not to write in the previous.

Answer (score 0):

Then create a new file with `w` with some extra identifier like

`"project-" + datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ".log"`